# What are the default return values for operator< and operator[] in C++ (Visual Studio 6)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, operators, operator-overloading, visual-studio-6

I've inherited a large Visual Studio 6 C++ project that needs to be translated for VS2005. Some of the classes defined operator< and operator[], but don't specify return types in the declarations. VS6 allows this, but not VS2005.

I am aware that the C standard specifies that the default return type for normal functions is int, and I assumed VS6 might have been following that, but would this apply to C++ operators as well? Or could VS6 figure out the return type on its own?

For example, the code defines a custom string class like this:

```
class String {
  char arr[16];
  public:
    operator<(const String& other) { return something1 < something2; }
    operator[](int index) { return arr[index]; }
};
```

Would VS6 have simply put the return types for both as int, or would it have been smart enough to figure out that operator[] should return a char and operator< should return a bool (and not convert both results to int all the time)?

Of course I have to add return types to make this code VS2005 C++ compliant, but I want to make sure to specify the same type as before, as to not immediately change program behavior (we're going for compatibility at the moment; we'll standardize things later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`operator<` returns a `bool` by default.

`operator[]` returns `int` by default (I *think*), but it should almost certainly be changed to return whatever the collection contains. For the String example you gave above, that would be a `char` or `wchar_t`.